# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando el consumo de un servicio con JavaScript, pero tengo problemas al realizar el mapeo me sale el error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

[image: Aquí el error en consola del navegador]

y aquí esta mi codigo.js :

function createNode(element) {

```
    return document.createElement(element);

}

function append(parent, el) {

    return parent.appendChild(el);

}

const td1 = document.getElementById('names');
const td2 = document.getElementById('flag');
const td3 = document.getElementById('capital');
const td4 = document.getElementById('population');

const url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all';

fetch(url)
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(function(data) {
        let names = data.results;
        //let flag = data.results;
        //let capital = data.results;
       // let population = data.results;

        return names.map(function (country) {
            let p = createNode('p');
            span.innerHTML = `${country.name}`;
            append(p);
        })
    })

    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })




Los datos que deseo obtener deben aparecer en esta tabla, es el único error que presenta:


 <h1>Paises</h1>
    <div class="col-md-7"> 
    <table class="table table-dark col-md-4">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Country Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Flag</th>
            <th scope="col">Capital</th>
            <th scope="col">Population</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td id="names"></td>
            <td id="flag"></td>
            <td id="capital"></td>
            <td id="population"></td>
    
          </tr>
```

La aplicación esta basada en este tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data, necesito consumir el servicio y obtener los datos del Json, gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner por favor qué valor te regresa data? Porque lo que se me ocurre es que no se recuperan bien los datos

Comment: Hola, cuando imprimo la data no me muestra nada en consola

Comment: El problema está en la recuperación de datos no en el map. Tienes que checar bien tu URL para obtener bien la información, también revisa qué tipo de petición recibe esa ruta.

Comment: De igual manera te recomiendo leer la documentación de [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 2):

No se de donde estás sacando el `results`, no lo necesitas, `data` ya contiene lo que quieres:

```js
fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.map(country => console.log(country.name));
    })
```

Comment: Nicolas, aquí cabe mencionar que en el tutorial de DO que estás siguiendo `data.results` es porque la respuesta de su API es de la siguiente manera `{results: {key1: value1, key2: value2, ...}}`, por eso acceden a data.results, en este caso no se recibe la misma estructura de datos; por lo tanto, `data.results` no existe